# Tizen ERROR- failed to connect to remote target [ip]

Tags: connection, tizen, samsung-galaxy-gear, tizen-studio, tizen-sdb

My `Samsung Galaxy watch Active` could not connect to **Remote Device Manager** in **Tizen Studio**, I tried everything, each time I get the following error

> failed to connect to remote target '172.19.44.160'

[image: the error figure]

**I had tried the following things:**

- Switch Bluetooth On to Off and restart my watch and vice-versa,
- Tried the Debugging mode On to Off with restarting and vice-versa
  several times ,
- Tried the developer option On with restarting several times,
- Also use the `sdb` connect commands,
- Disable `windows fireWall`
- I make sure that the watch and my PC even in the same network
- I also tried to make my watch `always on`
- I did a complete reset to the watch

but nothing of the above worked !!

also I want to know if the Tizen version affect this process, my Tizen studio version is 3.5 and I download the wearable 5.5  from package manager also I see in my watch that the Tizen version is 4.0.0.5.

Can anyone help me if this affect or not?

Comment: Check your target device IP again and try send a ping to your target first. It is more important than others (re-start, BT re-activation, always on...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was fixed when I used `mobile hotspot` instead of `wifi` connection.

Comment: So what's the solution to fix it with wifi? it's working with mobile hotspot but I need it to run with wifi : (

Answer (score 1):

I had tried to Reset my Active Watch and it worked correctly,
Can you try this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same solution, The problem was fixed when I used mobile hotspot instead of Wi-Fi connection. (As per Salsabeel Baraghithi's answer).

But for me when I turned off and disconnected my Wi-Fi modem and reconnect again, issue resolved. TV is now connecting through Wi-Fi as well.